# Preview static strings in Android Studio?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm having some problems reading what the actual SQL query is behind all this java code. This is just an example, though.

Is there an easy way to get the actual string behind this in Android Studio? It's really just a hard-coded string, after all.

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ARTICLES = "CREATE TABLE " +
    TABLE_ARTICLES + "(" + ARTICLES_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
    ARTICLES_KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "+ ARTICLES_KEY_PERCENT_FAT + " INTEGER, " +
    ARTICLES_KEY_PRICE + " INTEGER, " +
    ARTICLES_KEY_SALES_START + " TEXT, " + ARTICLES_KEY_SALES_STOP + " TEXT, " +
    ARTICLES_KEY_VOLUME + " INTEGER, " + ARTICLES_KEY_PRODUCT_GROUP + " TEXT)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Log.i or Log.d to print out SQL commands to the console for better readability. If you make the string public (temporarily) you can call it from your main activity.

`Log.i("SQLTEST", "create_table command: " + YourClass.CREATE_TABLE_ARTICLES);`

Comment: yeah, but I don't want to change code, compile, fire up the emulator and read the debug log to find out the value of a static string...